# Tomato leaf veins bloated and white

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes

I moved some tomato seedling to their own cups from their starting cells (seeded two plants to a cell) about three days ago. I noticed that some of the leaves on the plants are curling in and on closer inspection it looks like some veins on the leaves look white and bit puffy. Seems to affect a bit of the stem as well. I’ve been growing them inside til now, have started hardening them today. This seems to be an issue with maybe a third of the plants

Is this an issue and are there any steps I should take to deal with it? Should I isolate them from the healthy looking plants, pinch off leaves, etc., or is it just overwatering or shock?

[image]

[image]